Run SQL Server Agent T-SQL Job step under another Windows Account
This may look like a duplicate of this post, but the case differs. Here is the complete situation:

I have access to 172.31.50.98 using my Windows Domain Account

I have added 172.31.50.98 to my linked servers and set security settings to use current security context (as I cannot set a Windows Account as remote login)

I need this T-SQL to be run as a job using SQL Server Agent
DELETE FROM PAP_INVFactMain
INSERT INTO PAP_INVFactMain
SELECT
    *
FROM [172.31.50.98].GIG.PAP.KFI_INVFactMain



I don't have any option in SQL Server Agent to create a proxy for T-SQL execution (as you know). "Run As" option in step's advanced tab doesn't show Windows Accounts added as SQL Server logins (again, as you know). I have tried using "EXECUTE AS":
EXECUTE AS USER = 'companydomain\myaccount';
DELETE FROM PAP_INVFactMain
INSERT INTO PAP_INVFactMain
SELECT
    *
FROM [172.31.50.98].GIG.PAP.KFI_INVFactMain

But The above results in this error:
Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Login failed for user 'GIG\KFI-DC1-G950$'. [SQLSTATE 28000] (Error 18456).  The step failed.

This error means to me that SQL Server Agent is completely ignoring "EXECUTE AS" command. Also tried granting SQL Server Agent account "Impersonate Any User" permission with no luck. How can I force SQL Server Agent to run this step under my Windows Domain Account's context? (SQL Server 2019/SSMS 18/Windows 2019)
